# GMC transmission compatability

Tags: transmission, gmc, sierra, part-interchange, yukon

I have a*2012 GMC SIRRA 5.3, 6-SPEED TRANSMISSION*. Will a *2005 Yukon 5.3, 6-speed transmission* interchange or fit?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The only transmission available in the 2005 Yukon is a 4 speed. It could have been a 4L60E equipped with the 4.3/4.8/5.3 engines or 4L80E if equipped with the 6.0L engine. Your 2012 Sierra is a 6L80E. Neither of the available Yukon transmissions will work in place of your 6L80E. They might fit (ie: bolt to the engine), but they will not function, mainly because the transmission control is completely different between the two.